# Replace content of lines in file using sed, awk etc

Tags: bash, awk, sed, cut

I want to copy the content of span tag in line 31 and put it on line 5.

Input file:

```
...
<h1> 
    This is line 5, and it is a default string for all files
</h1>
  ...
  ...
<span id="foo"> This is line 31, different in every file </span>
...
```

Ouput File:

```
...
<h1>
   This is line 31, different in every file
</h1>
   ...
   ...
<span id="foo"> This is line 31, different in every file </span>
...
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Use node.js instead.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!  If you don't have a html (or xml) aware tool you can try the following

```
awk -F'[<>]' 'NR==FNR{if(NR==31)line=$3; next}
               FNR==5{$0=line}  1' file{,}
```

scans the file twice and depends strictly the format given, can be made more robust with extra work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are scripting it, you can do it like this

```
in_file=$1
out_file=output.txt

line=$(sed -n '31p' $in_file)
sed '5c'"$line"'' $in_file >$out_file
```

Since you wanted sed, there's a way to do it with sed in a bash script.  Since sed and awk are stream editors, you'd have to run them twice to get the results-- they go forward, not back.

Answer (score 0):

Go old school.  To replace the content of line 5 with the content of line 31 in the file `file.txt`, use:

```
printf '31y\n5x\n5d\nw\n' | ed file.txt
```

Absolutely no guarantees are provided.  Use at your own risk.